# Finding an object using tango device

Tags: google-project-tango

I want to create a small project using google project tango where I want to identify different objects like chairs and tables. I am using area learning mechanism. I want to know what else I need to use to identify different objects in 3D space.

Comment: Stack Overflow generally won't recommend off-site resources, or write your code for you.  However, once you start your project, if you run into any problems and can't find a solution, feel free to ask for help here.

Answer (score 1):

Object recognition isn't really a trivial problem and, depending on your approach and how flexible you want it to be, can become very involved and complicated. I would **strongly** recommend you do some research and read up on the topic first and make sure you have a good grasp on the basics.

That being said, there are existing Android projects available on GitHub, etc. that are capable of recognising various objects and I would recommend you have a look at those.

By the way, is there a specific reason you want to implement this on a Tango? Unless you plan on using the point cloud data instead of image data, object recognition should be able to work on a normal, non-Tango device as well.